# Programming - Principles and Practice using C++ - Chapter 3 Try this exercise - Repeated word detection

Tags: c++

Hi  I'm following Bjarne Stroustrup's  "Programming - Principles and Practice using C++" and I'm at chapter 3 doing the "Repeated word detection program", "Try This" exercise and I'm having some difficulty in understating the code below:

```
int main()
{
    string previous = " "; // previous initialised as white space 
    string current; // assign string varibable as current

    while(cin>>current) // read a stream of words
        {
            if (previous == current) // check if word is the same as last
            {
                cout << "repeated word: " << current << "\n";
            }

        previous = current;

        }


}
```

I don't understand why the program doesn't print to the screen as soon as two words are repeated, it only prints repeated when you press enter. If someone could explain this I would appreciate it a lot thanks!

Comment: in your while loop, `cin` reads the current line only after pressing enter

Comment: So when it reads the cin is that when the code inside the if statement is executed?

Comment: yes your program will block at `while(cin>>current)`. When you press enter `cin` will read the current line into `current` and execute everything inside the `if` statement

Comment: Sorry but this also confuses me, when "current" is read in does it treat the whole block of text entered as a single string and then compare that to "previous" or does it somehow split it up into individual words?

Comment: it will treat each word as a separate string. Say if you typed `hello world`, it will first loop with `current` as `hello` and compare `hello` to an empty string, than it will save `hello` as `previous`. The while loop will return and continue automatically with the word `world` as the new `current` and it will than compare `hello` as previous and `world` as current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's how cin works.

Cin reads the first word but only returns when a "\n" is detected. That's what happens when you press "enter". Which means that you can write as much as you want, but if you don't hit "enter", cin doesn't stops reading.

There's more behind cin and how all this mechanism works, but I think is enough for you to start. Try to read some more chapters!

Edit: changed words for clarity. Look at @Jaka Konda example in comments below.

Comment: A good note would also be, that it reads until \n, but it saves only the first word. If you type "This is a sentence", only "This" would be saved into a string.

Comment: True. If you want the whole line, you should use getline instead.

Comment: So once you hit enter does the code inside the while loop get executed?

Comment: So how come in the example he types in a whole sentence and it can find the repeated words if it only saves the first word?

Comment: Because you write the words and then press enter, so cin loops all the words until it finds "\n"

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop `cin` is evaluated as a `bool`, `cin` will read chars(spaces will be skipped) until a new line is found, this will trigger some flags to be set `false`, so on next iteration `cin` will be evaluated as `false` and your loop will stop.